# Wrong Google Cloud Translation from Spanish to Italian

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

When I translate this text:

```
{Código de calendario};{Nombre del calendario};
```

from Spanish to Italian I get:

```
{Calendar code}; {Calendar name};
```

that's English. Translating to any other language works fine.

I'm using C# and Google.Cloud.Translate.V3

Exactly the same when using https://translate.google.com/ website.

Regards,
Ramón García

Comment: Verified. It's a translation bug, I guess. It doesn't happen if you lower case (`{código de calendario};{nombre de calendario};`). Try using the "send feedback" button in the web interface. Sometimes someone notices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been created in the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for GCP and it can be tracked here:

> [Text in curly brackets translated to the wrong language](https://issuetracker.google.com/176740617)